# Different colors in LR/PS and web

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, srgb, icc-profile, prophoto

I have a problem with color profiles I guess...

1. So my Lightroom and Photoshop are both set to ProPhoto RGB.
2. I start with editing in LR first and then export to PS - so far so good - all colors look exactly the same on both applications.
3. Then when I'm done with editing in PS I convert to sRGB profile (Edit > Convert to Profile). After that action colors still remain the same inside PS.
4. However when I export the image (Save for Web or Export As) and check COnvert to sRGB and Embed Color Profile and then when open it with FastStone or Windows Photo app or any web browser colors look dull and desaturated compared to what they looked inside PS and LR.

What am I missing? For years I been editing images the same way as I described above and everything was working perfect until now. Did I change anything by accident and what could it be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real issue with your process; except that the third step is redundant and destructive.

Try turning on your color space warnings in PS's color setting preferences and then opening one of your exported images... see if PS throws a color space warning telling you that the image is in sRGB or not. If it does throw the warning (it should) then you may have some conversion settings applied incorrectly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So what was the problem is that Chrome has a lot of bugs and colors are not reproduced same as expected! There is no problem with Edge or any other browser!

Comment: I have never experienced a problem with Chrome incorrectly displaying properly tagged sRGB images. The only thing I have ever heard of is that if using Mac OSX Chrome needs to be restarted if you change your monitor/profile in order for it to pick up the correct/current profile (e.g. using a laptop and switching to an external monitor). The issue you describe sounds more like improper color space tagging.